# ProgressBar in Android - how to make it smoother using fragments and threads?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, loading, lag

I am currently writing an app that is based on communicating with my server.
Right now I'm trying to animate loading circle while user is trying to log in. My problem is - it's animation isn't really smooth. I believe it's because it is running on main thread, same as other "heavy operations".

Here is some code:

```
public void headClick(View v){
    showLoadingFragment();
    powerLogin();
}

public void showLoadingFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    LoadingFragment loadingFragment = new LoadingFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.logsign_content, loadingFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I know, this is a bit ... unusual. Normally I replace fragments on this screen, and the only place that is currently free to show this Progress bar is populated by fragments. My idea is to hide all the user options (buttons, text fields and all) and put a clear fragment with circle in it.

Here is the Fragment implementation (right now it's as standard as it gets):

```
public class LoadingFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View loadingFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_loading, container, false);

    return loadingFragment;
}


}
```

And the UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I searched for similar problem, however the solutions are not really suitable for my approach. For example, I'm using retrofit library for my communication, not classic AsynchTask (co I can't show ProgressBar while doing stuff). And because I use fragment, I can't really keep it always hidden... because it's not there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by "heavy operations"?

Comment: @Salem Worst case scenario looks like this: Check if user logged in (no) -> Log user to server -> Download userdata (e.g. rank, name, etc.) -> save everything for future use -> launch "main" activity with Google Map view. It is no data crunching by all means... but for some reason this circle stutters, isn't it?

Comment: If you are using HTTP calls they need to be made outside the main thread.

Comment: @Salem I believe, that Retrofit is covering that for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own progress bar with frame animation OR 
if you want complex progress bar with thread you can use surfaceView or glSurfaceView